# How to implement upvote/downvote via over-riding a model manager in Django/Python

Tags: python, django

I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.5.
In models.py, I have:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=250, blank=True)
    with_votes = LinkVoteCountManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

class LinkVoteCountManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self): 
        return super(LinkVoteCountManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(votes=Count('vote')).order_by('-votes')

class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
```

Next, in views.py I have:

```
class LinkListView(ListView):
    model = Link
    queryset = Link.with_votes.all()
```

The above correctly gives me a count of votes aggregated per link. Now, taking it to the next level, I want to incorporate downvotes into this set up as well. I included a `value = models.IntegerField(default=0)` attribute in Vote class (to capture -1 and 1 values), and changed `votes=Count('vote')` to `votes=Count('vote.value')` in my Custom Manager.

Unfortunately, it seems that is not how Custom Managers work. I'm now stumped as to how to implement upvote/downvote in this setup, in an efficient, elegant way. Being a Django newbie doesn't help of course.

Any gurus who can shed light on how they would traverse this problem are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not how *aggregation* works: your problem is there, and has nothing at all to do with managers.

For a start, to correctly calculate a sum of positive and negative votes, you need `Sum`, not `Count`.

And to traverse a relationship in a query in Django, you use the double underscore syntax, not dots. So:

```
...annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value')).
```

Comment: Thanks for the protip Daniel. I've started this book to get a clearer understanding of syntax and usage: http://zetcode.com/lang/python/

Comment: Btw the problem isn't perfectly solved yet. Recall that I set `value = models.IntegerField(default=0)` in `Vote class`. Now once I do `return super(LinkVoteCountManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value')).order_by('-votes')` in the model manager, I ought to get '0' for every freshly created link's vote value right? Instead, I get "None". Seems `default=0` in `value = models.IntegerField(default=0)` is not doing its job.